# HTML5 Canvas Layering

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have 2 different codes using HTML5 canvas. I want to be able to layer the two together. I want the video to appear in the background of the animated square. Is there a way to do that in HTML5 Canvas?

square animation:

```
 <canvas id="ex1" width="525" height="200" style="border: 5px solid black;" ></canvas>

 <p id="text"> Increase/Decrease Speed</p>
 <input type="button" value="+" id="btnAdd">
 <input type="button" value="-" id="btnSub">
<script>

 var x = 0;
var y = 15;
var speed = 10;
var isRight = true;

document.getElementById('text').innerText = speed;

document.getElementById('btnAdd').addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    if (isRight) speed++;
    else speed--;
    document.getElementById('text').innerText = speed;

});

document.getElementById('btnSub').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (isRight) speed--;
    else speed++;
    document.getElementById('text').innerText = speed;

});

function animate() {

    reqAnimFrame = window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

    reqAnimFrame(animate);

    x += speed;

    if (x <= 0 || x >= 475) {
        speed = -speed;

        isRight = !isRight;
    }
    document.getElementById('text').innerText = speed;

    draw();
}

 function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("ex1");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.clearRect(0, 0, 525, 200);
    context.fillStyle = "#ff00ff";
    context.fillRect(x, y, 40, 40);
}

animate();

</script>
```

video canvas:

```
 <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript">                
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.src = 'gold.mp4';
    video.controls = true;
    document.body.appendChild(video);

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    video.onplay = function() {
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
            draw();
    };

    function draw() {
        if(video.paused || video.ended) return false;
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
            setTimeout(draw, 20);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: simple solution is to call, on a rAF, the video drawImage first then the square draw.

Answer (score 2):

First you want to set the position property of the canvas elements to `absolute`. Then for each canvas, you want to set their `z-index`.

For example, if you want element with class `canvasOne` to be behind `canvasTwo`

```
canvas { 
    position: absolute;
}

.canvasOne {
    z-index: -1;
}

.canvasTwo {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

What the absolute [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) achieves is that it allows you to set multiple elements to the same position because it takes the elements out of the normal flow of the page.

[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) allows you to control the stack ordering of the elements, or, in other words, the order of the element layers.

Answer (score 0):

everything you need is to set a different z-index css property of canvases
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Please don't use w3schools. Their materials are often [incomplete and inaccurate](http://w3fools.com). This article definitely isn't "everything", as it doesn't explain concept of different [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) that are a common pitfall. Please use MDN or W3C's official WebPlatform.org instead.